# run a function after 60 seconds of user being on website not on a single page

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are trying to make a load a JQuery function 60 seconds after the user has landed on the website.

We can do this per page but cannot do this for the who visit. *e.g.* the user could browse 4 pages within 60 seconds and then it would load...

Our code for page load is :

```
$(window).load(function(){

  setTimeout(function() {
       loadPopup();
  }, 500);
})
```

How can we acheive this for the website visit and not per page?

Comment: Store the first visit time. In a cookie/localStorage/...?

Comment: Hi Graham, thank you for your reply, how would i do this?

Comment: I read this article on cookies when I dealt with them. http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: Should this behavior reset after a while, a day, a year, ever?

Answer (score 2):

Just try with:

```
var time = $.cookie('time') || 0;    
if (time < 60) {
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        if (time >= 60) {
            console.log('over 60 seconds!');
            clearInterval(interval);
        } else {
            $.cookie('time', ++time);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

It uses [jQuery Cookie library](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/).

To reset counter just add `time = 0` in the `if` clause.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/25B9s/2/)

Comment: You may also want to clear the interval after 60 seconds have elapsed (assuming you don't want the cookie to track more time and the message repeating).

Comment: @Paul Or we can still use cookies and check the time of last visit.